# Print all rows from a nested Left Join + Union MySQL query

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

I have a query that calculates information for a revolving monthly retainer. The Project has a certain number of hours assigned to it each monthly period, with periods starting at different times of the month (e.g., February 5th to March 4th). The columns of the query result include:

1. Project Name
2. Total Hours Logged
3. Monthly Hours Remaining
4. Last Day of Period
5. Days Remaining

For example, Project A has 15 hours logged to it, with 5 hours remaining in the monthly period. The last day of the period is November 17th, with 3 days remaining from today.

The current Query takes 4 tables that are joined using a left join to print all of the Clients even if there are no hours logged, then it uses a nested subquery (lines 8-86) to calculate columns 2, 3, 4, and 5. However, column 4 and 5 do not print, they just show as always NULL. (Those are Last Day of Period and Days Remaining).

You can see the schema + query code at the SQL fiddle link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/12

How can I get column 4 and 5 to print the data and not be null when there are no Hours Logged? I think I may need an additional left join but I am not able to get a solution. If you have any suggestions it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Daniel see the results for each inner query and verify where the problem happens. To go thru the entire sql is too much asking. Post only the problematic section.

Comment: Hi nawfal - thanks for your comment. The inner queries all work correctly - the specific question is how to get those to work together with the outer query. I believe this is a question of updating only some lines of code, hence having the total query makes more sense. Previously I have shared only parts of a query, only to find that it was not helpful for answer-providers as compared to showing the full query. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: the reason you are getting null is because the inner query is returning no entry at all. Now correct that. Only you know.. Try from the first fiddle link you posted

Comment: I see that - I need to update the data to make there be a result, then I will update the sql fiddle link. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I updated the query to simplify the inner query and added new schema which will return a result for Client A (previous data was not in current month so it returned an empty result). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/3 . I also updated the main link in the question to this one. The question is the same - why doesn't "Last Day" show up for the other 3 clients for which there is a Last Day calculated in the Inner Query. Same for Days Remaining - that one is calculated in the outside query (line 5), plus left join on line 7 of entire inner query which is what gets all Clients to print.

Comment: +1 for the very nice use of SQLFiddle. Made working on this so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

When there has been no hours logged, the left join to the nested query returns nulls for the columns you're having trouble with.

The answer is to provide values for them when they are null and us `ifnull()` to use those value when the left join returns nulls:

```
select
...
ifnull(<left joined value>, <value when there's no join>),
...
```

See the [working solution in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/6).

Incidentally, some values you are returning from the inner query, particularly the "last day" value can be derived directly from `client` (as seen in my solution). It's best to keep your queries as simple as possible - don't get data in a complicated way when there's an simpler or more direct way.

Comment: +1 Excellent. Didn't go myself into what those paragraphs of queries actually did! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However the issue is that the Last Day as well as Days Remaining depend on if client.start_day_of_month < or >= day_of_month(curdate()). If you see the full inner query, there is a union of 2 statements that return the values based on the condition: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/12 (see lines 20 and 41). That being said, your solution wouldn't account for those conditions, hence my issue in resolving this question - I think something has to be done in the inner queries instead of the outer query.

Comment: I made an updated version where I am calculating the Days Remaining in the inner query to account for the condition described in the previous comment. However I am getting an error of unknown column for expr4. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/16 . I'm trying to use expr4 (Last Day calculation) to calculate expr5 (Days Remaining). If you have any tip on what's wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: you have removed the inner query so `expr4` no longer exists. Instead, replace `expr4` with the code for the previous version's `expr4`.

Comment: expr4 is set in line 11 and line 33. It is the same as in the previous version. However now I added a new line (12, 34) to calculate the days remaining based on the last day that was calculated in expr4. However, it's telling me that expr4 is not a defined column, even though it is defined in line 11 and 33, and referenced again in line 12 and 34. Is there some issue with using expr4 to calculate expr5? Not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not thorough with the idea of `LEFT JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` results in all rows from the outer table. Its otherwise called `LEFT Outer JOIN` (contrary to `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`). In your case the inner query results in only record with client id = 4. See the last clause `X on X.id=client.id`. Now what do you expect the results to be?

```
OUTER TABLE (client table)
id = 1, 2, 3, 4

INNER TABLE 
client id = 4

ON X.id=client.id
```

An `INNER JOIN` would result in just one record since there is only matching record - for id = 4.

But a LEFT JOIN would result in all 4 records from outer table but the values for invalid fields will be `NULL`. Here except for client id 4, there is no valid records from inner table, hence they will be null.

To get more clarity you will have to see the id field along the records. [Try this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc830/5)

You can see the other answer as to how to fill those `NULL` fields..

Comment: to answer your question, the expected result would be: 1: Client B, 0, 30, 2012/12/5, 21 days remaining; 2: Client C, 0, 25, 2012/12/7, 23 days remaining; 3: Client Empty, 0, 30, 2012/12/5, 21 days remaining; 4: Client A, 0, 30, 2012/12/5, 21 days remaining

Comment: @DanielC how is it possible when inner query is returning just one record? You have to adjust the inner query actually accordingly. Thats a big ask from my side here. I ask you to kindly debug the inner query and find where the issue lies with and what can be done. If you can not find a solution, but find the problem, then ask that. You're problem lies with the inner query (or insufficient data) surely :)

Comment: that is the purpose of this question - there is an issue both with the inner and outer query... the question is how to get it to work as desired, using either some other type of join inside, or some if conditional function outside. If you are not interested in answering further, then no hard feelings. Thank you.

Comment: There's no issue with outer query. And that's why you get the output for one value correctly. To understand what is "desired" from that big a query is too much asking. Instead try yourself to analyze where lies the root of the problem in inner query not giving you desired output. Thanks too :)

Comment: actually the inner query gets the output. anyway I think you are not interested so no need to comment further. I've spent several weeks on the query and now I'm asking on SO for some help. If you're not interested, no need to comment and say that things work when they do not. Thank you

Comment: @DanielC when inner query gives you just one result (hope you agree on that part) how do you expect the query to fill the void values obtained by a "left join" ? Please first understand how left join works. If you do, then tell us what logic should be implemented when there are not enough values returned from inner query. Instead of merely asking how do I get rid of empty cells, tell us what logic you want to rely on to fill those voids. Left join will lead to null entries if inner query doesn't have sufficient values.

Comment: You may try inner join, but then that will give you just one record. Just one record that matches, but a complete record with no null values! No hard feelings, just saying..